# Hidden form relate to targetID

Tags: php, forms, select, mysqli, edit

i'm currently trying to solve the edit product, when i pressed edit product and is works great that show everything and allow me to see product image and text filed for us to update it.

After I pressed submit, is updated into the database but after that I got errors in same page relate to inside of forms where it said

```
<label>
    <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID  ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Make change" />
</label>
```

This error said

```
Notice: Undefined variable: targetID in C:\VertrigoServ\www\shopone\admin\data\edit_product.php on line 147 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0010352200{main}( )..\edit_product.php:0 " />
```

please see  full forms section and see at the near end of line...

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="edit_product.php">
  <table width="80%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

      <tr>
           <?php echo '<td width="36%" rowspan="9" align="right">  <img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . '/' . $screenshot .'" width="351" height="402" />  </td>'; ?>
        <td class="text-box1">Product Name:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="product_name" type="text" class="text-field1" id="product_name" value="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><!-- Icons --></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-box1">Product Category:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="product_category" type="text" class="text-field1" id="product_category" value="<?php echo $product_category; ?>" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><!-- Icons --></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-box1">Product Retail Price:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="product_retail_price" type="text" class="text-field1" id="product_retail_price" value="<?php echo $product_retail_price; ?>" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><!-- Icons --></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-box1">:Product price:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="product_price" type="text" class="text-field1" id="product_price" value="<?php echo $product_price; ?>" /></td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-box1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-box1">Images</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2"><!-- Icons --></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label>
          <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID  ?>" />
          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Make change" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

and in the php section...

```
<?php 
$dbcs = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "shopone");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbcs))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
// Parse the form data and update company information to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $pid = $_POST['thisID'];
    $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
    $product_category = $_POST['product_category'];
    $product_retail_price = $_POST['product_retail_price'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];

$sql = "UPDATE product SET
    product_name='$product_name', 
    product_category='$product_category', 
    product_retail_price='$product_retail_price',
    product_price='$product_price'
    WHERE product_id='$pid'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcs,$sql);

if(!$sql)
{
print "error";

}
else 
{
header("product.php");
}}


// Gather these companies full information for inserting automatically into the edit form below on page
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id='$targetID' LIMIT 1";
  $result=mysqli_query($dbcs,$sql);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
               $product_id = $row["product_id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $product_category = $row["product_category"];
             $product_retail_price = $row["product_retail_price"];
             $product_price = $row["product_price"];
             $screenshot =$row["screenshot"];

        }
}

mysqli_close($dbcs);
?>
```

Does anyone know what is mean and how to solve that!

Answer (score 0):

When you prss the submit button you change the variable from $_GET to $_POST is another script in php I think that you have to implement.
But if you wanna try.. try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id='$targetID' LIMIT 1";
  $result=mysqli_query($dbcs,$sql);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
               $product_id = $row["product_id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $product_category = $row["product_category"];
             $product_retail_price = $row["product_retail_price"];
             $product_price = $row["product_price"];
             $screenshot =$row["screenshot"];

        }
}
else{
   if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
      $targetID = $_POST['pid'];
   }
}
```